# Creating a landing page for ionic app

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a Login page in ionic for a mobile app.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/smv/pen/KdZXeB)

The page is supposed to

1. have a blue background
2. display the App-title at the center of the page
3. display a login button below the App-title

I have partially got all of this working, however I am not sure if I am using the correct ionic techniques.

my css looks like this:

```
.login-page {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  h1{
     position: relative;
     top: 100px;
     left: 40%;
     font-size: 24px;     
     margin: auto 0;
  }
  a {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 45%;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a small demo for you,

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/oTFbHQ?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true " class="view-bg-blue">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>        
  <ion-content padding="true">
    <h3 class="text-center">Welcome To Landing Page</h3>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h4 >My App</h4>
                     <a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm" ng-click="open()">Lets Go</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**style.css**

```
.view-bg-blue
{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.text-center
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you need any additional feature,Please let me know?Thanks

Comment: you have added in-line styles..any particular reason ?

Comment: No particular reason.You can use separate css file.Please check my updated answer

Comment: Important Error! Plunker Not found!